# Create function with a dynamic list of parameters

Tags: function, t-sql, parameter-passing

I am creating a function and as its parameter, I need a dynamic list of numbers.  It is my understanding that I can't do this as a parameter, so I'm trying to define the list in a CTE.  Below is the beginning of my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRCPolicyDetailByForm (@formcategory INT)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN

WITH FormBase_CTE AS (
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN @formcategory = 1 THEN (SELECT 1,2,3)
            WHEN @formcategory = 2 THEN (SELECT 4,5)
            ELSE NULL
            END AS Forms
)
```

I get this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is there any other workaround for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You cant return more than one result in CTE, the THEN (Select 1,2,3) wont work.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with putting this in a function?

Comment: You can't use case expression like this - it can only return a single scalar value for each case. Also, I agree with Owain Esau - this seems like an XYProblem.

Comment: I need a function that can accept a dynamic list of numbers that will be used in an 'IN' statement later on in the function.  Sometimes it will be two numbers, sometimes three.  Not sure if there is a workaround to this.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE @formcategory = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 WHERE @formcategory = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 WHERE @formcategory = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 WHERE @formcategory = 2
```

Or You can use STRING_SPLIT -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

```
DECLARE @FILTERS NVARCHAR(MAX) = CASE WHEN @fromcategory = 1 THEN '1,2,3' ELSE '4' END
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@FILTERS, ',')
```

**EDIT:** Use XML for old server version

```
DECLARE @formcategory int = 1
DECLARE @filter xml = CASE WHEN @formcategory = 1 THEN '<v>1</v><v>2</v><v>3</v>'
                           ELSE '<v>4</v><v>5</v>'
                      END

SELECT T.c.value('.', 'int') AS Value FROM @filter.nodes('/v') AS T(C)
```

Comment: That STRING_SPLIT function is pretty cool.  Unfortunately, it looks like my database compatibility level is not 130 and cannot be altered.

Comment: You can use XML